# Is it possible to use a package/macro only locally?

Tags: preamble

I would like to create a LaTeX file from several different other LaTeX files that might use different definitions of the same macros or might use incompatible packages.

Is it possible to have within a same LaTeX file different “preambles” corresponding to different parts?

If not, do you suggest any idea?

## edit

Here is what I want to achieve.
It is for a webapp: several users type their LaTeX file with their own preamble. They only type the body of the document and maintain two other files: a file of macros and a file of “`\usepackages{...}`”.
Then I want to use their files and put them in a “global” .tex file, with additional content (header, etc.)

I want to make this process automatic.

Comment: Sure thing! It depends on how you want to construct it. Incompatibilities are usually resolved using conditions (like package options or `\if`-statements). Could you provide more detail regarding what you have in mind?

Comment: @Werner I have updated the question.

Comment: So you wanto to merge the usepackage files? And this automatic? Do you look for something like http://www.tex.ac.uk/FAQ-multidoc.html? Please add what you really want to do with some details how files will look and about which kind of packages we are talking.

Comment: latex will not include a package twice so most of the time it's going to be Ok to input all the "usepackage"  files from all of the documents.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is no; LaTeX is designed around the model of typesetting single document only.

The `combine` package attempts to combine documents with multiple preambles but it's not a seamless process by any means. For some combinations of packages it works okay, but for other packages it simply fails.

I would generally recommend you try to organise the system so that each user's document is typeset to a separate PDF file and then the PDF files are combined.